# Where can I order pressed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit Desktop CDs with professional graphics?

Tags: 64-bit, 12.04, canonical

Canonical [have confirmed today](http://shop.canonical.com/enquiries.php?ID=30636&g=f595eb63e7e010bff0db57cc4880e3fe) they will be shipping 32-bit Desktop CDs of 12.04 from their store, with the [product page](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976) just updated to reflect this.

I prefer 64-bit, I thought it was now the default offering based on several articles like [this one](http://2buntu.com/1136/1204-desktop-to-have-64-bit-as-the-default/)(2buntu.com).

I want to order pressed CDs in 64-bit to hand out to people. They look professional, and I know from experience that people are more inclined to try Ubuntu from one of these over a generic CD that I make.

**Who offers pressed 64-bit 12.04 Desktop CDs that look professional, like the 32-bit version Canonical offers?**

Comment: If canonical wont do it just download 64 bit ubuntu and order for 32 bit ubuntu ,then burn the downloaded iso and put it on the 32 bit cd cover :p

Comment: @I'mnotthisperson Canonical's professional-looking packaging containing a home-made CD I write on with a Sharpie is not what I want. The pressed CDs have graphics printed on them, and the look is consistent with the outer packaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On-Disk.com does; [here](http://on-disk.com/product_info.php/products_id/1435/osCsid/4eh42mtebqnuliinn01po4bpq7) is their page for Ubuntu 12.04. I am sure there are others as well, but I have always had good experiences with on-disk.com.

Comment: Does On-Disk do any graphics on the CDs and packaging? There are no product images at that link, just generic images of USB drives, etc. People pay me to 'fix' their Windows machines with an Ubuntu install and the look of the materials is important. I don't mind downloading and burning disks for personal use, but I'm after something that looks professional when I go out promoting Ubuntu.

Comment: When I used them they did images on the CD/DVD that looked very professional. I used them for a security conference and had them make BackTrack CDs for me... we ended up being the busiest booth as all the security guys wanted a 'pretty' BackTrack CD. They even worked with me to choose a graphic for the CDs since I was doing them in quantity. They may do the same for you, but with Ubuntu they likely already have an image chosen. I am not sure if they have the ability to do any printed sleeves though.

Comment: I have good and bad news. The good is I accepted your answer because I only asked about the CDs, which On-Disk does. They wrote me back though, and confirmed they do not do sleeves. I should have worded the question better I guess. I wrote Canonical again and I'll update the question if I get any more news. Thanks.

Comment: I posted this on G+ to see if anyone knows of other places... the sleeves are likely the issue since there are devices that press and print on CDs now... but making a folding sleeve takes a bit more work.